# Copy data from script using imacros and paste it to another tab

Tags: imacros

How i can copy data(6 digit password) from page source/script using  imacros and paste it to another tab.

I try this code

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=script ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
```

SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.split('%20')[9];")
SET !VAR2 EVAL("var s=\"{{!VAR1}}\"; s.split('.')[0];")

TAB T=2
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD ATTR=ID:otp CONTENT={{!VAR2}}

SET !EXTRACT NULL

But i'm unable to paste it to another tab.
Please help me..!